# Multiple lines of text/ label in mixed italic and regular fonts in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations

I have trying several options to add significance Levels as text labels to a plot. I got the result using geom_richtext() in the ggtext package. Although the labels turn out fine, I am getting the code pasted on the graph/ plot. Any idea how to avoid that! Or is there any other option?

```
geom_richtext(x = 1.15, 
                            y = 0.2, 
                            label.color = "black",
                            label = "<b>Significance Levels</b><br>ns <i>p</i> > 0.05<br>* <i>p</i> <= 0.05<br>** <i>p</i> <= 0.01<br>*** <i>p</i> <= 0.001<br>**** <i>p</i> <= 0.0001")[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I was not allowed to post the graph since I am not an experienced user. It's just a label for the plot. Nothing connected to the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(gridtext)
library(ggplot2)

label <- "<b>Significance Levels</b><br>ns <i>p</i> > 0.05<br>* <i>p</i> <= 0.05<br>** <i>p</i> <= 0.01<br>*** <i>p</i> <= 0.001<br>**** <i>p</i> <= 0.0001"

ggplot(BOD, aes(Time, demand)) +
  geom_point() + 
  annotation_custom(richtext_grob(label), ymin = 0.2)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks a ton :)

Comment: for some reason this doesn't work for me. Even if I open a clean R session, and copy and paste your code, the font all looks the same on the plot (the breaks work, but the bold and italics formatting don't apply). Any guesses why? Thanks

Comment: I get the graph shown with ggplot2 3.3.6, gridtext 0.1.4 and "R version 4.1.3 Patched (2022-03-10 r81883)" under  "Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)".  What versions and platform do you have?    `packageVersion("ggplot2"); packageVersion("gridtext"); R.version.string; win.version()`